# -[<CALayer: 0x5584190> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, iphone-sdk-3.0

```
-[<CALayer: 0x5584190> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size (255211754908294243945860531626574872576.000000, 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000)
```

Can any one please tell me what's this warning about? The app is crashing on some devices showing this.

Any suggestion would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 12):

I believe this is caused because the layer is too large and I expect this will cause issues buffering to an image for drawing.

I had this problem with a large UIView with relatively simple graphics and solved it by using a CATiledLayer

To do this, include the following in your UIView subclass to enable tiling:

```
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}
```

Comment: Swift 4 version: `override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CATiledLayer.self }`

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered this error in a view controller that was being presented in a popover. The "ignoring bogus layer size" error was occurring when the popover was presented, and as a result a text field within the view controller did not render its text.

In my case, moving a `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` call from `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidAppear` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a bit of time trying to find the answer to a similar question, I was getting:

`[<CALayer: 0x37d540> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size (nan, nan)`

but only on a device, not on the simulator.
My problem was due to the fact that I was loading images out of the `applicationCacheDirectory` and it turns out the files had a mix of upper and lower cases in my project director.  But in the Cache directory on device, they were all changed to lower case.  Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while working with *UISegmentedControl and I was customizing a text using this method:

```
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:(@{UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont regularFontWithSize:13.f],
                                              UITextAttributeTextColor: controlsSelectedColor,
                                              *UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset:* **@0**}) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The error also occurred only on the device and was because of incorrect attributedText parameter *UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset*
I've set there an *NSNumber*, but according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893-CH3-SW43) it should be *UIOffset* struct wrapped with *NSValue*.
I've changed it to *[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetZero]* and it worked.
The question is why it didn't work on the Simulator.

So check your attributed text if You've used it. It could be such kind of magic.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a TableViewController embedded in a nav controller when segueing to detail VC.  Changing from a show (push) to show (detail) fixed it.  Make sure and clean.

Comment: I had this issue also.  It was fixed by removing all constraints and recreating them.  They looked correct, but I must have done something wrong which only became apparent inside a navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using `-UIViewShowAlignmentRects YES` as a startup variable. When I switched it off, the problem went away. Bug in Xcode?