# UISearchBar shifting position in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Not sure why this is happening, I have a UISearchBar in my navigation bar, however when I start scrolling the SearchResultsTableView, the searchbar seems to jump its position and i get the error warning: `[<CALayer: 0x16550840> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size`

Here are the screenshots of the searchBar shifting in position.

[image]
[image]

It's pretty minimal but very noticeable. Any ideas? Thanks!

Here's the code i use to setup my search bar

```
if (!self.cardSearchDisplayController) {
    CGFloat searchBarHeight = 64.0;
    self.cardSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, searchBarHeight)];
    self.cardSearchBar.delegate = self;
    self.cardSearchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

    self.cardSearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:self.cardSearchBar contentsController:self];
    self.cardSearchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    self.cardSearchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.cardSearchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.cardSearchDisplayController.searchBar;
    self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
}
```

Comment: post your code. how to set searchbar in navigation bar

Comment: Did you use CALayer anywhere in your code

Comment: Nope i didn't use CALayer anywhere in my code. Edited the searchbar setup above!

Comment: Any news on this problem? I'm experiencing the same bug.

Answer (score 1):

For **ios 7** you have to used this one ,in the **viewDidLoad** fixed it for me:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

May it will help you.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't seem to be helping for me, getting weird results using this... thanks though!

Comment: For your error may it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757334/calayer-0x5584190-display-ignoring-bogus-layer-size

Comment: Odd though, I did not do anything with CALayer in my code